# How to enumerate weeks over years in SQL/SNOWFLAKE

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

I have been toying with making a data model housing a calendar in SQL.

What I am stuck right now is to have the weeks enumerated (as a way to order them for visualization purposes later on, like "easily coding pick last 4 weeks").

This has proven easy in Excel, but I want a way to build it from a query as the calendar is to be recreated each time the data model runs (create/replace the table).

What I have tried (*but fails after the year changes*) so far is this (*I do not know how to pick the previous record from a field I am currently creating*):

```
CASE WHEN week_of_year <> coalesce(lag(WEEKOFYEAR("DATE"),1) over (order by "DATE"),1) 
    THEN lag(WEEKOFYEAR("DATE"),1) over (order by "DATE") +1 
    ELSE lag(WEEKOFYEAR("DATE"),1) over (order by "DATE")
```

The desired **GROUPED** output is this (*said grouped as the calendar should have data for each day*):

| YEAR | WEEK_OF_YEAR | week_order |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2000 | 49 | 50 |
| 2000 | 50 | 51 |
| 2000 | 51 | 52 |
| 2000 | 52 | 53 |
| 2001 | 1 | 54 |
| 2001 | 1 | 55 |
| 2001 | 2 | 56 |
| 2001 | 3 | 57 |

Answer (score 1):

if you are want a value that increments over the years and weeks, across data that has values for all combinations then should work:

```
SELECT year, 
    week_of_year, 
    row_number() over (order by year, week_of_year) as week_order
```

Answer (score 0):

What about

```sql
row_number() over (order by YEAR, WEEK_OF_YEAR) as week_order
```

Comment: if your answer is for giving the third column in the example output, then instead of being constant over year end like the third column, you will restart at 1. Aka you just recreated `week_of_year`

Comment: Good point, will update